# 'downloadFunc' is not a function (ReactJS custom hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following custom hook that will be triggered when the user presses a button. It will call an endpoint to my server that will download a group of files as a .zip file:

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { basePath } from '../../config/basePath';

async function downloadWorkInstructions(fileId) {
  const downloadFunction = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${basePath}/files/download-all/${fileId}`, {
      method: 'GET',
    });

    return response;
  };

  return downloadFunction;
}

export function useDownloadWorkInstructions() {
  return useQuery(['uploads'], () => downloadWorkInstructions());
}
```

My hook gets imported in this React screen

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
....
import { useDownloadWorkInstructions } from '../hooks/workInstructions/useDownloadWorkInstructions';

export function WorkInstructions() {
    ...
    const { data: downloadFunc, isLoading } = useDownloadWorkInstructions();

    ...

    const handleDownloadFiles = async (workInstructionsId) => {
        try {
            if (!isLoading) {
                const response = await downloadFunc(workInstructionsId);

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    // Handle successful download if needed
                } else {
                    console.log('Download error:', response.status);
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Download error:', error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Box padding={5} paddingTop={12}>
                <Grid container spacing={4}>
                    {workInstructionsData != null && workInstructionsData.map((workInstructions) => (
                        <Grid item key={workInstructions.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                                    ...
                                    <Button
                                        size="small"
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            handleDownloadFiles(workInstructions.id);
                                        }}>
                                            Download
                                        </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
}
```

However, I always get the following error: `downloadFunc is not a function`. I have tried many approaches, like modifying the custom hook, print what `downloadFunc` has so I cadjust my code, among many other things. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the `data` returned by `useQuery` is the actual data, and not a query function. Furthermore you have other errors that prevent the code from working.

You should read the `useQuery` documentation. I think that you're using [v3](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/reference/useQuery), but my solution should work with [v4](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery) as well.

Fetch returns a promise out the of box, so let use query handle it instead of the redundent async/await:

```
function downloadWorkInstructions(fileId) {
  return fetch(`${basePath}/files/download-all/${fileId}`, {
    method: 'GET',
  });
}
```

You need to pass the `fileId` to `useQuery` as a key, and as a parameter to the fetch function. You should also disable the query if `fileId` is empty:

```
export function useDownloadWorkInstructions(fileId) {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['uploads', fileId], // use fileId as key
    queryFn: () => downloadWorkInstructions(fileId), // use fileId as part of the download
    enabled: !!fileId, // enable only if fileId is not empty
  });
}
```

You should hold a state of the current `fileId`, and update it when another is clicked. When the `fileId` state changes, `useQuery` would react, and return `data` or `error`. You should handle the return value in a `useEffect` block according to the returned `status`. Use the `isLoading` flag to disable the buttons, and prevent users from initiating a call while another is in progress:

```
export function WorkInstructions() {
  const [fildId, setFileId] = useState(''); // holds the current file id
  
  const {
    data, // data is returned when enabled, fetch succeeds and no error
    status,
    error,
    isLoading
  } = useDownloadWorkInstructions(fildId);

  ...
  
  // handle the return values according to the status
  useEffect(() => {
    if(status === 'success') {
      // Handle successful download if needed
      console.log('Download error:', data);
    }
    
    if(status === 'error') {
      // Handle error if needed
      console.log('Download error:', error);
    }
  
  }, [data, status, error]);

  return (
    <>
    ...
  {data?.map((workInstructions) => (
    <Grid item key={workInstructions.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      ...
      <Button
        size="small"
        onClick={() => {
          setFileId(workInstructions.id); {/* set the fileId */}
        }}
        disabled={isLoading} {/* disable button while loading */}
        >
        Download
        </Button>
    </Grid>
  ...
  </>
  );
}
```